# Convert RDD[(K,V) to Map[K,List[V]]

Tags: scala, rdd

How can i convert a RDD of tuple2 (Key,Value) with duplicate Keys into a Map[K,List[V]] ?

Input example:

```
val list = List((1,a),(1,b),(2,c),(2,d))
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(list)
```

Output expected:

```
Map((1,List(a,b)),(2,List(c,d)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `groupByKey`, then `collectAsMap`:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((1,"a"),(1,"b"),(2,"c"),(2,"d")))

rdd.groupByKey.collectAsMap
// res1: scala.collection.Map[Int,Iterable[String]] =
//   Map(2 -> CompactBuffer(c, d), 1 -> CompactBuffer(a, b))
```

Alternatively, use `map/reduceByKey` then `collectAsMap`:

```
rdd.map{ case (k, v) => (k, Seq(v)) }.reduceByKey(_ ++ _).
  collectAsMap
// res2: scala.collection.Map[Int,Seq[String]] =
//   Map(2 -> List(c, d), 1 -> List(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupByKey` , `collectAsMap` and `map` to achieve this like below

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((1,"a"),(1,"b"),(2,"c"),(2,"d")))
val map=rdd.groupByKey.collectAsMap.map(x=>(x._1,x._2.toList))
```

Sample output:

```
Map(2 -> List(c, d), 1 -> List(a, b))
```